# Why doesn't `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` allow me to change the vertices?

Tags: javascript, three.js, render, vertices

I have this function that is being called repeatedly, but the vertices aren't changing:

```
function renderChart() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderChart);
    // Copy frequency data to frequencyData array.
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData); //frequencyData is an array that changes over time.  

    var dat = 79600;  
    var step = dat/frequencyData.length
    var f = 0;  
    for(v=0; v<dat; v+=step){
        globe._baseGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        globe.points.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        globe._baseGeometry.vertices[v].z = globe._baseGeometry.vertices[v].z * frequencyData[f]
        globe._baseGeometry.vertices[v].y = globe._baseGeometry.vertices[v].y * frequencyData[f]
        globe._baseGeometry.vertices[v].x = globe._baseGeometry.vertices[v].x * frequencyData[f]
        f++; 
    }
}

// Run the loop
renderChart();
```

If I run it it in a `$(document).ready(function(){...` it will run successfully once.  What changes

Answer (score 0):

The solution is discussed here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8021

> As discussed in [#7179](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7179), you can't reassign the vertices array. Use copy() instead."